# Animated background in flash - high CPU usage

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm facing a problem here - I've hired a freelancer, to make a design for my flash app. And everything was fine, untill I saw this. It was an animated background. It has about 100 tweened movie clips, that do pretty much the same - simple rotation tween, but cpu usage on that background only reaches 17-20%. Its high for such a small effect. 
I've tried to optimize it - removing all code, and leving just timeline based tween, but that didn't solve my issue.

Maybe someone can help me?

You can see swf example here: http://drabuna.com/problem/AnimatedBackground.swf
And get .fla here: http://drabuna.com/problem/AnimatedBackground.fla

Comment: hire someone who knows the newer Stage3D APIs, blitting and/or a creative-programmer (yes, they do actually exist) who doesn't need to rely on timeline scripting and CPU intensive vector tweening.

Answer (score 3):

If it were me I would create one instance in the library and duplicate it. I am willing to bet it would be less of a resource hog. I agree with TheDarkIn1978, this type of animation should require no time-line at all. Read this link.

http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?223798-ActionScript-3-Tip-of-the-Day/page12&p=1939827#post1939827

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the supplied .fla file it seems that the designer has already just created one animation object and created multiple instances of it.

I would hazard a guess that the high CPU usage is due to the animated graphics being filled with a 15% alpha fill.

Perhaps you could try replacing the vector shape that is filled with a 15% tint for a bitmap png that already has the transparency applied. Like this...

[image: graphic png]

Or how about creating a looping flv of the background and play that instead.

Comment: Converting to png haven't change a thing=( I guess, flv is not an option due to its result size, which will be much bigger.